# Using ForeignKey and ManyToManyField in Django model

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, foreign-keys

I'm trying to set up this Django endpoint to create a new post.

MODEL

```
class UserPosts (models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL,            related_name='posts_created')
    text = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='posts_liked')
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

SERIALIZER

```
class UserPostsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserPosts
        fields = ['id', 'user', 'text', 'likes', 'timestamp', 'user_id']
        depth = 1

    user_id = serializers.IntegerField(write_only=True)
    likes = UserSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)


#NOT SURE IF RELEVANT, BUT THE USERSERIALIZER LOOKS LIKE THIS

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
```

VIEWS

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def get_all_posts(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        posts = get_list_or_404(UserPosts)
        serializer = UserPostsSerializer(posts, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = UserPostsSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            serializer.save(user=request.user, user_id=request.user.id)
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

If I test the endpoint in Postman, I get a 400 error Bad Request saying "user_id": "this field is required". I've set up ForeignKey fields exactly like this in the past and it worked. But I haven't used a ManyToMany field in this way before. I'm thinking the issue is in my serializer?

Comment: `user` or `user_id`? I expect the former, not the latter?

Answer (score 2):

Omit the field from the serializer: you pass this explicitly in the `.save()` method, and set `user` to `read_only`:

```
class UserPostsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    likes = UserSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)
    extra_kwargs = {'user': {'read_only': True}}

    class Meta:
        model = UserPosts
        fields = ['id', 'user', 'text', 'likes', 'timestamp']  # no user_id
```

While not necessary, in the view you can boost efficiency with a [**`.prefetch_related(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related):

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def get_all_posts(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        posts = get_list_or_404(UserPosts.objects.prefetch_related('likes'))
        serializer = UserPostsSerializer(posts, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = UserPostsSerializer(data=request.data)
        # the serializer will not look for user/user_id
        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            serializer.save(user_id=request.user.id)
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

---

**Note**: Especially for Django REST API views, it is better to work with class-based views since it can automate a lot, like injecting a context in the serializer, easily checking (object)permissions. While one can work with a function-based view, it often does not pay off to do so, especially for "basic scenario" views.

---

**Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.comen/stable/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.comen/stable/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).